# How to see the debug internal server errors when there is an error in POST done via AJAX in Django

Tags: ajax, django, debugging, post

I have defined many views doing 'manual' ajax processing like:

```
@require_POST
def do_something(request, ...)
    ....
    <some code that bugs>
    ...
```

How to get the normal django stacktrace page out of this?

Because of limitations of my current setup (Django is run on a remote host using PyCharm remote debugger and the project is on a NFS share) stopping the server and restarting the server under debugger is not the optimal solution, especially because most of the problems would be easily spotted from the django error page with stacktrace and local variables.

Any other debugging ideas also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view any ajax response in separate "window" with either Firefox or Google Chrome. In Chrome it is the Network tab in developers console.